# How I input image feature in tensorlfow?

Tags: image, tensorflow

i have a question related with the tensorflow.

I used DNNClassifier model.

I want image feature, sure many other column exist
(ex> age, type..)

In age case, i use tf.feature_column.numeric_column(age).

however, i don't know input image feature.

please, help me..thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Image processing is essentially numeric, so you can use `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` for pixels. Just make sure you set the `shape` argument to the image's size:

```
image_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('pixels', shape=[image_width * image_height])
```

[This article](https://codeburst.io/use-tensorflow-dnnclassifier-estimator-to-classify-mnist-dataset-a7222bf9f940) provides a more thorough discussion of classifying images with a `DNNClassifier`.